# How do I set CodeIgniter validation rules by element type?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is there a way to set a validation rules that says something like "All textboxes are required"?

The only info I can find suggests that rules have to be set for each individual element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that in a single go. You have to specify validations for each of the fields you specify in your form.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'required');
```

**EDIT**: if it is too lengthy. Go for Javascript validation.